# What is the correct way to inject PHP data in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2

Suppose to have some user data in PHP, stored in an array:

```
[
  'name' => 'Tester',
  'level' => 999,
  'email' => 'tester@acme.com'
]
```

You have to pass this array to your VueJS application, how would you pass it?

I was thinking about writing this array in a `script` tag so JS will parse it, but I also think there should be another way more safe and easy.

I'm not going to use XHR because this data should be sent just on the first request, this array is not going to change in future, so XHR is not needed (one request is enough).

Comment: Is it a SPA? If its sent on the first request then why do you need to request it again? Put it in session storage.

Comment: Yes @LawrenceCherone, it's a SPA. No, I don't need to request them again, I'm just asking the correct way to send them the first time.

Comment: It depends on the login response, if its doing an ajax request which responds with json, put it in there, if its a normal form post to a HTML page which is a bunch of containers for the rest of the app then, use a script tag. For JWT you would respond with the auth token then do an additional call for any data you need so diverging to put it in HTML is perhaps not the best thing to do.

Comment: Yes but I don't want to make other requests like XHR, I want to pass the data with the first request.

Comment: Then your only option is to place it in a script tag :/, perhaps you should change the question title if your ruling out the correct way.

Comment: I just think it's useless to use XHR in this case, because the client will send 2 requests instead of one, and this will increase the server load.
I want to avoid sending another one request. I will proceed by putting all in a script tag, but I think there is a better way.

Comment: Do you want to pass data to `vue component`?

Comment: Yes @VaibhavrajRoham

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to make a XHR request, to be honest.

But... It makes absolutely no difference. Just toss it in a `script` tag and then use it in the Vue instance. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass PHP `array` as `prop (property)` to vue component. I use following approach in my projects.

Let's say, your component name is `dashboard`, then your file where you are calling component will look like below

```
.....
<!-- Other html php stuff -->

<!-- Pass values to vue component -->    

<dashboard :details="<?php echo json_encode($your_array); ?>"></dashboard>

....
```

Now you can define prop as below in your `dsashboard component`

```
....
 props: ['details'],
....
```

which you can directly access as `this.details` in the form of array.

Hope this way help you.